# How can I customize Prettier setting using WebStorm IDE without installing package

Tags: visual-studio-code, webstorm, prettier

How can I export all Prettier linter setting from Visual Studio Code and using that in WebStorm?

I am the only person from team that use WebStorm as programming IDE and not Visual Studio Code. Lots of linter Prettier setting required from Visual Studio Code user setting json file.

How can I use that in WebStorm without installing Prettier package or change package.json from project?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Prettier in WebStorm without installing it, Prettier doesn't come bundled with the IDE. Once you install it per instructions at https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html, you can create a [prettier configuration file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html) in the project root folder to set up Prettier according to your preferences